# jQuery retrieving results in one row instead of table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which is used for retrieving a value from some external resource, the problem is that when the value is displayed every character is in a new row and before every character there is a column with numbers, like a character counter.

Current HTML display:

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>k</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>p</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>p</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>.</td></tr>
```

I want to display it in a single row without counting numbers:

```
<tr><td>akpp.</td></tr>
```

I first tried removing the key and then value the value but then I only get numbers in new rows without the value.

Part of the jquery code

```
function prettydump(obj) {
    ret = ""
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
      ret += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
    });
    return ret;
  }

var info = $('<div class="uploaded_info"/>');

        $(info).append($('<div class="data"/>').append(prettydump(data.result.path)));
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show a sample of the expected result, please?

Comment: <tr><td>akpp.</td></tr>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want your function to look like.

```
function prettydump(obj) {
  ret = "";
  ret += "<tr><td>";
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    ret += value;
  });
  ret += "</td></tr>";
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: No problem. I guess you can mark this answer as the correct one now.